# Вытащить из url переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery

как вытащить

```
comment-35911630
```

из текущего урл

```
3114513-chej-borw-vkusnye-istorii-ot-shef-povara-anons-prjamogo-jefira-na-fishkinet.html/comment-35911630/
```

Comment: если ето просто определенная секция, сплит по слешу и берите нужний индекс, если нет, опишите нормально вопрос

Comment: то урл на комментарий, и при переходе по ссылке, мне нужно вырезать comment-35911630, проверить существует ли он и опустить страницу к комменту с атрибутом data-comment="comment-35911630"

Comment: окей, ето определенная секция урла ? сплит подходит ? или может бить где угодно, но всегда ничинаеться на слово "комент" ?

Comment: начинается со слова comment-

Comment: она всегда находится  конце урла

Comment: Идеологически - так: `tmp=url.split("/"); comment=tmp(ubound(tmp)-1);`. При отсутствии финального слэша - минус один убрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант которому пофигу, где находиться комент :

```js
const url = '3114513-chej-borw-vkusnye-istorii-ot-shef-povara-anons-prjamogo-jefira-na-fishkinet.html/comment-35911630/',
  c = 'comment-',
  comment = url.split('/').filter(e => e).find(e => e.startsWith(c) && +e.replace(c, '') > 0)

console.log(comment)
console.log(`comment exsists = ${!!comment}`)
```

Вариант когда комент только последняя секция :

```js
let url = '3114513-chej-borw-vkusnye-istorii-ot-shef-povara-anons-prjamogo-jefira-na-fishkinet.html/comment-35911630/'
const c = 'comment-'

url = url.slice(-1) === '/' ? url.slice(0, -1) : url
const comment = url.split('/').slice(-1)[0]

console.log(comment)
console.log(`comment exists = ${comment.startsWith(c) && +comment.replace(c, '') > 0}`)
```

Comment: а как проверить еще есть ли после слова comment тире и цифры больше 0?

Comment: Можно написать регулярку, но я в них полный ноль, ну а тире можно ж просто добавить к слову комент..

Comment: добавил какую-никакую проверку на цифры, точнее на число

Answer (score 1):

[regexp](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) в помощь

```js
const teststring = "3114513-chej-borw-vkusnye-istorii-ot-shef-povara-anons-prjamogo-jefira-na-fishkinet.html/comment-35911630/"

const commentID = teststring.match(/comment-(\d+)\/$/)[1]
console.log(commentID)
```

Comment: падает если комента нету (

Comment: Об этом не спрашивалось. достаточно стандартной проверки типа 

const commentID = teststring.match(/comment-(\d+)\/$/) ? teststring.match(/comment-(\d+)\/$/)[1] : default;